# Stackoverflow error while calling another method within one

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I'm trying to compute the combination

`procedure(factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r))`.

When I call the `factorial` method from within the `combination` method, when running I get a `stackoverflow error` before the calculation.

The instructions read `"This method should receive two integers as its parameters, n and r. Your combination method should call the factorial method inside its definition by using it in the following formula:"`

Any help will be appreciated we haven't really covered stackoverflow so I'm a little lost. Thank you!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab6_Perea{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to Set calculator. Please select the calculation you want to perform \n\t1. Power \n\t2. Factorial \n\t3. Combination \n\t4. Permutation");
    int option = sc.nextInt();

    switch(option){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please enter the base and exponent: ");
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("The answer is: " + power(x, y));
        break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            int z = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("The facotrial of " + z + " is " + factorial(z));
        break;   

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Please enter 2 numbers to calculate the Combination: ");
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("The total combination is: " + combination(a, b));
        break;

        case 4:
            // FIX ME call Combination method
        break;
    }

}
public static int power(int n, int m){

    if(m==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * power(n, m-1));  
}

public static int factorial(int n){
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (n * factorial(n-1));
}
public static int combination ( int n, int r){
    int combo =factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r));
    return combo;
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.StackOverflowError due to recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368406/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-due-to-recursion)

Comment: `factorial(n-r)` Is `n < r`?

Comment: `factorial(n-r)` if `n - r` is negative then this will recurse forever

Comment: Your factorial method says that if n == 0 return 0.  0! = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
public static int factorial(int n){
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * factorial(n-1));
}
```

And you do not have to test n for positivity. The recursion you wrote went in StackOverflow because n-r<0 and your original rule (if n==0) was never encountered.

Comment: Please if you'd like check this as the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

Use `return 1 if n==0`

```
public static int factorial(int n){
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * factorial(n-1));
}
```

Please `check n>=r condition.`

Hope, this will work!

Comment: You do not need to check n>r if the test is n<1

Answer (score -1):

It's because there is some limit on the number of recursions one can use.
To overcome it, you can use a for loop inside the factorial function.

Comment: No the first problem is that the functional function is wrong because it always returns 0. The correct function is: public static int factorial(int n){
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * factorial(n-1));
}

Comment: Even if you correct that, you will still get stackoverflow error. To avoid that you can just use for loop with condition n>0

Comment: Yes you can test if n<1 then 1 and recursion and if n<r stops at the start